# MySQL select string with \ in it - string is part of IN ()

Tags: mysql, string, placeholder

From a MySQL database, I am trying to select a column which has two occurrences of `\` in it. The `\` surrounds text. It occurs in one term of a list of terms that I am trying to search for using `IN ()`.

**Here is the query that I am trying to write:**

```
SELECT
q.pk_id,
q.test_temp,
q.financ_course,
q.etc_id
FROM quckdbase q
WHERE q.display IN ('Martin','Google test document.',"\'Margaret course economics\'.");
```

As you can see, the **last term in the `WHERE` clause is the cause of the problem**. For this term, the exact entry in the database is

```
\'Margaret course economics\'.
```

There is a period, `.`, at the end of the entry.

**What this query does:**
It selects the values in 4 columns if the column `display` contains an entry that matches any one of `Martin`,`Google test document.`,`\'Margaret course economics\.'`.

Is there a way to include the third search term in the `IN ()` so that it can be searched for in parallel with the other 2 terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a literal string value, escape the backslash with another backslash character. Also, a single quote can be escaped by preceding it with another single quote.

To "match" the string, you could do this:

```
WHERE q.display IN ('\\''Margaret course economics\\''.')
```

The first backslash is an "escape", the second backslash is interpreted as a literal backslash character. The two single quotes within the string literal are interpreted as a literal single quote.

For testing, to confirm the value returned by this literal:

```
SELECT '\\''Margaret course economics\\''.' AS val
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was aware of the escape for the backslash but I did not know about the same for the single quote. Your answer worked.